# disassemble code for 2 formats of printfs

Tags: c, disassembly

I am trying to understand reasoning for seg fault with dissemble code.

```
Case 1.
char *p = NULL;
printf("%s", p);
O/p: No crash. it give me null. Further looking at disassemble code, it shows this one.


Dump of assembler code for function printf@plt:
        0x00000000004003b8 <+0>:     jmpq   *0x2004aa(%rip)        # 0x600868 <printf@got.plt>
        0x00000000004003be <+6>:     pushq  $0x0
        0x00000000004003c3 <+11>:    jmpq   0x4003a8
    End of assembler dump.
```

While i am trying to further go beyond this but do not know how to move to next set of instructions and what exactly it does.

Case 2.

```
int
main()
{
    char *p = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", p);
}
```

It leads to seg fault. 
Disassemble code:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:

0x00000000004004c4 <+0>:     push   %rbp
0x00000000004004c5 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000000004004c8 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x00000000004004cc <+8>:     movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
0x00000000004004d4 <+16>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
0x00000000004004d8 <+20>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
0x00000000004004db <+23>:    callq  0x4003b8 <puts@plt>
0x00000000004004e0 <+28>:    leaveq
0x00000000004004e1 <+29>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disassemble puts
Dump of assembler code for function puts@plt:
    0x00000000004003b8 <+0>:     jmpq   *0x2004aa(%rip)        # 0x600868 <puts@got.plt>
    0x00000000004003be <+6>:     pushq  $0x0
    0x00000000004003c3 <+11>:    jmpq   0x4003a8
End of assembler dump.
```

Can u please help me to identify what assembler instruction is leading to seg fault?

Comment: None of the assembler code you posted is relevant. The difference is that `printf("%s\n", p)` is compiled to `puts(p)` whereas `printf("%s", p)` actually calls `printf`. `printf` `%s` itself checks for null pointers and prints them as `(null)`. `puts` blindly dereferences its argument and thus crashes.

Comment: One of my friend was asked this in interview and they informed him to go beyond puts() and printf() in disassembled code.

Comment: OK, so find the actual code for `printf` and `puts`. What you posted is just a `jmp` instruction.

Comment: Thanks. But i am not much familiar with disassembled code and not able to move  beyond this point as when i say disassemble this is what i get but do not know how to get complete dump. (gdb) disassemble puts
Dump of assembler code for function puts@plt:
   0x00000000004003b8 <+0>:     jmpq   *0x2004aa(%rip)        # 0x600868 <puts@got.plt>
   0x00000000004003be <+6>:     pushq  $0x0
   0x00000000004003c3 <+11>:    jmpq   0x4003a8

Answer (score 1):

```
0x00000000004003b8 <+0>:     jmpq   *0x2004aa(%rip)        # 0x600868 <puts@got.plt>
```

Two important codewords here:

```
GOT -> Global Offset Table
PLT -> Procedure Linkage Table
```

This indicates it calls puts from dynamic library. Address of puts is not know at disassembly only time. Program must be run in order to allow dynamic linker bind address of library function to PLT slot.

What you need is:

```
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40053e: file c.c, line 9.
Starting program: /home/josef/DEVEL/test/test/a.out 

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at c.c:9
9           char *p = NULL;
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400536 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400537 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000040053a <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
=> 0x000000000040053e <+8>:     movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400546 <+16>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000040054a <+20>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x000000000040054d <+23>:    callq  0x400410 <puts@plt>
   0x0000000000400552 <+28>:    leaveq 
   0x0000000000400553 <+29>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disassemble puts
Dump of assembler code for function _IO_puts:
   0x00007ffff7a84d60 <+0>:     push   %r12
   0x00007ffff7a84d62 <+2>:     mov    %rdi,%r12
   0x00007ffff7a84d65 <+5>:     push   %rbp
   0x00007ffff7a84d66 <+6>:     push   %rbx
   0x00007ffff7a84d67 <+7>:     callq  0x7ffff7a9d9b0 <strlen>
   0x00007ffff7a84d6c <+12>:    mov    0x34fafd(%rip),%rbx        # 0x7ffff7dd4870 <stdout>
   0x00007ffff7a84d73 <+19>:    mov    %rax,%rbp
   0x00007ffff7a84d76 <+22>:    mov    (%rbx),%eax
   0x00007ffff7a84d78 <+24>:    mov    %rbx,%rdi
   0x00007ffff7a84d7b <+27>:    and    $0x8000,%eax
   0x00007ffff7a84d80 <+32>:    jne    0x7ffff7a84ddf <_IO_puts+127>
   0x00007ffff7a84d82 <+34>:    mov    0x88(%rbx),%r8
   ......
```

Now you see what is inside `puts`. You can go forward and disassemble `strlen`

```
(gdb) disassemble strlen
Dump of assembler code for function strlen:
   0x00007ffff7a9d9b0 <+0>:     pxor   %xmm8,%xmm8
   0x00007ffff7a9d9b5 <+5>:     pxor   %xmm9,%xmm9
   0x00007ffff7a9d9ba <+10>:    pxor   %xmm10,%xmm10
   0x00007ffff7a9d9bf <+15>:    pxor   %xmm11,%xmm11
   0x00007ffff7a9d9c4 <+20>:    mov    %rdi,%rax
   0x00007ffff7a9d9c7 <+23>:    mov    %rdi,%rcx
   0x00007ffff7a9d9ca <+26>:    and    $0xfff,%rcx
   0x00007ffff7a9d9d1 <+33>:    cmp    $0xfcf,%rcx
   0x00007ffff7a9d9d8 <+40>:    ja     0x7ffff7a9da40 <strlen+144>
   0x00007ffff7a9d9da <+42>:    movdqu (%rax),%xmm12
   0x00007ffff7a9d9df <+47>:    pcmpeqb %xmm8,%xmm12
   0x00007ffff7a9d9e4 <+52>:    pmovmskb %xmm12,%edx
   0x00007ffff7a9d9e9 <+57>:    test   %edx,%edx
   0x00007ffff7a9d9eb <+59>:    je     0x7ffff7a9d9f1 <strlen+65>
   ......
```

Good luck with analyzing all the code :)

Comment: I am doing as u mentioned but i am still getting same assembled code. Let me know what am i missing. (gdb) break printstr.c:5
Breakpoint 6 at 0x4004cc: file printstr.c, line 5.
(gdb) start.. Breakpoint 6, main () at printstr.c:5
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004004c4 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   ..
=> 0x00000000004004cc <+8>:     movq   $0x0,-0x8(%rbp).. (gdb) disassemble puts
Dump of assembler code for function puts@plt:
   0x00000000004003b8 <+0>:     jmpq   *0x2004aa(%rip)        # 0x600868 <puts@got.plt>

Comment: What if you don't set breakpoint - just open gdb and run `start`?

Comment: ok - last resort solution. Compile it statically `gcc yourfile.c -static`. Then all the code will be in executable.

Comment: static worked but still not sure why other one did not work while i am following similar steps.